Jenkins Master slave Architecture setup : SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connect timed out", retrying in 15 seconds
enter image description here
Getting this error , when trying to connect slave instance to master instance in Jenkins
Looking for Fixes for above Issue
SSH is working when trying to connect parent to slave instance via terminal , but via Jenkins configuration its throwing error.
Please help!!

First of all, screenshots of logs are less helpful than you might think. Copy and paste text. Double check your .ssh/config because it sounds like jenkins and whatever user you are connecting as use different IP or port.
